# Firebase Analytics fire custom event from PHP

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-analytics

is there a way to fire a custom event (that is already configurated) from PHP or is there any other alternative how to execute the Firebase Analytics event from PHP code?

Answer (score 3):

To send events from your server-side code to Google Analytics you can use the [Measurement Protocol API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4). Sending events takes a [REST API call](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events) in there.

To get comfortable with the API, I recommend looking at the JSON in the [GA4 Event Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/ga4-event-builder/) tool, that is linked from the documentation too.